# Can I get api key facebook for android application

Tags: android, facebook, api

I want to develope an facebook chat application but I don't know how to get the api key?
Please help me get the api key, I only see App Id and app secret.

Answer (score 0):

For getting an Facebook API key in Facebook.Just go to facebook developers page and create an fb app and you will get your API key and secret. Refer : [This link for getting API key](http://www.mytechshout.com/how-to-get-facebook-api-key.html)